# How to make a .NET API Endpoint more performant, scalable and handle high load

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a .NET 7 application which is handling a couple of thousand users a day. At peak times, the application consumes all the resource on the IIS server which it runs.

I know the next step is containerization and all that good stuff but for now I want to get the best out of what I've got. I'm quite new to developing, and I've not got a computer science background and I can't profess to fully understanding async or multithreading.

As an example, I have an endpoint that is probably called around 300 times a second. The database backend is SQL Server 2019 (Standard) and I'm using Entity Framework Code First. Its using .NET Identity for authentication on these endpoints.

Any advice on how I can make these two snippets the absolute fastest they could be, and handle the most amount of concurrent users without knocking out my server, and a brief explainer why so I can adopt similar paradigms throught my app.

**Get Result**

```
[Route("/mobile/result/{matchtype}/{referenceid}/{lastchecked}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetResult(MatchType matchType, long referenceid, string lastchecked)
{
    DateTime datetocheck = DateTime.Parse(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(lastchecked));

    Result response = new Result();
    if (matchType == MatchType.League)
    {
        response = _context.Results
            .Where(i => i.Fixture.Id == referenceid && i.LastUpdated >= datetocheck)
            .Select(i => new Result()
            {
                ReferenceId = referenceid,
                MatchType = matchType,
                ResultId = i.Id,
                HomeFrameScore = i.HomeScore,
                AwayFrameScore = i.AwayScore,
                HomeHandicap = i.HomeTeam.Handicap,
                AwayHandicap = i.AwayTeam.Handicap,
                MatchStatus = i.Status
                //Set scores for comps
            })
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (response == null)
            return NoContent();

        response.Frames = new List<Frame>();

        response.Frames = _context.ResultFrames
            .Where(i => i.Result.Fixture.Id == referenceid)
            .Select(i => new Frame()
            {
                ResultFrameId = i.Id,
                FrameNumber = i.FrameNumber,
                HomeBreak = i.HomeBreak,
                HomeDish = i.HomeDish,
                HomeForfeit = i.HomeForfeit,
                HomeLockedIn = i.HomeLockedIn,
                HomeScore = i.HomeScore,
                AwayBreak = i.AwayBreak,
                AwayDish = i.AwayDish,
                AwayForfeit = i.AwayForfeit,
                AwayLockedIn = i.AwayLockedIn,
                AwayScore = i.AwayScore,
                Status = i.FrameStatus,
                MatchFormatSectionId = i.MatchFormatSection.Id
            }).ToList();

        var resultframeplayers = _context.ResultFramePlayers
            .Where(i => i.Result.Fixture.Id == referenceid)
            .Select(i => new FramePlayer()
            {
                ResultFramePlayerId = i.Id,
                Number = i.Number,
                ResultFrameId = i.ResultFrame.Id,
                Joker = i.Joker,
                HomeAway = i.HomeAway,
                PlayerId = i.PlayerSeasonTeam != null ? i.PlayerSeasonTeam.Player.Id : 0
            }).ToList();

        foreach( var rf in response.Frames)
        {
            rf.HomeFramePlayers = resultframeplayers.Where(i => i.ResultFrameId == rf.ResultFrameId && i.HomeAway == HomeAway.Home).ToList();
            rf.AwayFramePlayers = resultframeplayers.Where(i => i.ResultFrameId == rf.ResultFrameId && i.HomeAway == HomeAway.Away).ToList();
        }
    }

    return Json(response);
}
```

**Lock In Section**

```
[Route("/mobile/lockinsection")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> LockInSection([FromBody] FrameResultData data)
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

    if (data.MatchType == MatchType.League)
    {
        var checkcaptain = ValidCaptain(data.MatchType, data.ReferenceId);

        if (checkcaptain == false)
            return BadRequest("Not a valid captain for this match");

        var captainhomeaway = CaptainHomeOrAway(data.MatchType, data.ReferenceId);

        if (data.LockIn.HomeAway != captainhomeaway)
            return BadRequest("Captain locking in for the wrong team");

        foreach(var frame in data.LockIn.Frames)
        {
            var resultframe = _context.ResultFrames
                .Include(i => i.Result)
                .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == frame.ResultFrameId);

            if (data.LockIn.HomeAway == HomeAway.Home)
                resultframe.HomeLockedIn = LockedIn.True;

            if (data.LockIn.HomeAway == HomeAway.Away)
                resultframe.AwayLockedIn = LockedIn.True;

            _context.Update(resultframe);
        }

        var result = _context.Results.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Fixture.Id == data.ReferenceId);
        result.LastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
        _context.Update(result);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
    else
    {
        //Competition
    }

    return BadRequest();

}
```

Comment: What is peaking out on IIS? Is it CPU or RAM? You might simply not have enough. A container within the same constraints will do the same thing (in fact it might be worse because now you have another layer of overhead). It seems like your controller is exploding data out. There's might be a more efficient way to do that in one line.  If this is on SQL Server, I'm pretty sure you can actually just write a single query to do all that work and it'll send back nested JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two related, but separate concerns to consider with performance. There is the time needed to execute a block of code, and then there is the question of what the code waiting for that response could otherwise be doing.

For performance there are a couple adjustments I can suggest. In the read you can simplify the call to a single query by leveraging the navigation property references:

```
  response = _context.Results
        .Where(i => i.Fixture.Id == referenceid && i.LastUpdated >= datetocheck)
        .Select(i => new { Result = new Result()
        {
            ReferenceId = referenceid,
            MatchType = matchType,
            ResultId = i.Id,
            HomeFrameScore = i.HomeScore,
            AwayFrameScore = i.AwayScore,
            HomeHandicap = i.HomeTeam.Handicap,
            AwayHandicap = i.AwayTeam.Handicap,
            MatchStatus = i.Status
            Frames = i.Frames.Select(f => new new Frame
            {
                ResultFrameId = f.Id,
                FrameNumber = f.FrameNumber,
                HomeBreak = f.HomeBreak,
                HomeDish = f.HomeDish,
                HomeForfeit = f.HomeForfeit,
                HomeLockedIn = f.HomeLockedIn,
                HomeScore = f.HomeScore,
                AwayBreak = f.AwayBreak,
                AwayDish = f.AwayDish,
                AwayForfeit = f.AwayForfeit,
                AwayLockedIn = f.AwayLockedIn,
                AwayScore = f.AwayScore,
                Status = f.FrameStatus,
                MatchFormatSectionId = f.MatchFormatSection.Id,
           }).ToList();
        }, 
    MatchPlayers = i.Players.Select(p => new FramePlayer()
        {
            ResultFramePlayerId = p.Id,
            Number = p.Number,
            ResultFrameId = p.ResultFrame.Id,
            Joker = p.Joker,
            HomeAway = p.HomeAway,
            PlayerId = p.PlayerSeasonTeam != null ? p.PlayerSeasonTeam.Player.Id : 0
        }).ToList();
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

What this does is read your match with the Frames in a single query, then separately also loads all Players based on an expected navigation property I called "Players" as an example. So the resulting anonymous object contains the Result with it's associated frames, and  a collection of all players for the result. From there you can go through the frames to filter the appropriate home vs. away set rather than going to the DB again. You could query the result frame players internally when populating the frames but it is probably more efficient to load them all once and filter. This lets the database do much of the work without several round trips.

For the update... I would simply load the result and it's associated frames once then update the fields: So instead of this:

```
    foreach(var frame in data.LockIn.Frames)
    {
        var resultframe = _context.ResultFrames
            .Include(i => i.Result)
            .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == frame.ResultFrameId);

        if (data.LockIn.HomeAway == HomeAway.Home)
            resultframe.HomeLockedIn = LockedIn.True;

        if (data.LockIn.HomeAway == HomeAway.Away)
            resultframe.AwayLockedIn = LockedIn.True;

        _context.Update(resultframe);
    }

    var result = _context.Results.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Fixture.Id == data.ReferenceId);
    result.LastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Which if you are updating 3 frames will execute 4 queries, This can be improved to just use a single query using:

```
var result = _context.Results
    .Include(r => r.Frames)
    .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Fixture.Id == data.ReferenceId);
```

then find the applicable Frames in the result and alter those values, along with the Result.last modified etc.  Or, if a Result has many frames and you only want a specific set:

```
var frameIds = data.Login.Frames.Select(i => i.ResultFrameId).ToList();
var result = _context.Results
    .Include(r => r.Frames.Where(f => frameIds.Contains(f.Id))
    .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Fixture.Id == data.ReferenceId);
```

So if a result contains dozens of frames and we only care to update a small number then it may be more efficient to just load the frames we care about rather than all of them.

The next thing would be to *not* use `Update()` when loading tracked entities, just update the values and call `SaveChanges()`. `Update()` is a method for updating detached entities. The issue with `Update()` is that it will generate an update SQL statement for all columns whether anything changed or not. With tracked entities, EF will generate an Update SQL statement for just the columns that changed, and only if anything actually changed.

Your API methods are set up for asynchronous execution, though all code inside them is for the most part synchronous. This means the call will block and do nothing until the code completes. Asynchronous does not make the code being executed faster, if anything it makes it slightly slower, but it does free up the caller to do other things while that code is executing. In the case of a web API, the waiting code is the threads that are handling web requests against the server. In a synchronous world, if you have 100 worker threads you can receive 100 requests then request 101 has to wait until one of the workers is done. The only way to improve responsiveness is to make the code faster or increase the resources so the server can handle 200 requests at a time etc. That can be vertical scaling (bigger hardware) or horizontal (more listeners with load balancing) There are limits and bottlenecks such as database connections. Once code is executing as fast as it can, and you're averaging say 150ms/request but want to ensure the web server is responsive, this is where asynchronous can help. It may mean the code takes 160ms to run instead of 150ms, but frees up the web request thread while it is executing. The 101th request doesn't wait 150ms to start, it might only wait 45ms. The response back to each request may take 160ms best case or a bit longer but each server instance can generally handle more requests. Since your methods are already set up as `async`, you can improve responsiveness by awaiting reads with `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()`, and methods like `SaveChangesAsync()`. Just be sure to `await` them.

Hopefully that gives you a few things to think about and try, feel free to update the question with specific problem areas that you think might be improved.

Comment: This is a fantastic and comprehensive answer, and described in terms I understand. Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that the SqlClient connection pool defaults to a 100 connection limit.  But running more than 100 concurrent requests probably won't increase your throughput unless the SQL Server is pretty big.

Answer (score 0):

For 1000 mCPU (1 core) .NET can handle around 150-300 distinguished requests at best, which converts to 1ms-3ms per request. I mean, if your request is in batches it can be **far greater rps**, but your clients usually come in for **single entity - single client**, you can't force them, so that's it.

Your task is to combine them so you can lower IO/CPU (lowering latency in result). The best way to do this - caching and RPC (remote procedure call).

1. Caching - is straightforward you can store it in memory or in some **low latency scalable service** like DynamoDb,Cassandra,MongoDb,Redis,CDN,etc to lower memory consumption of FE (frontend) services.
2. Remote procedure call - message broker (rabbitmq,kafka,eventhub,redis,etc)+ BE (backend) service. It is where you put your update/insert/delete or heavy reads.

How does it work in practice?

1. Client comes with update for entity to your FE
2. You push event in message broker (kafka) and send OK
3. Message broker compacts multiple similar requests
4. BE take those in batches
5. Batch is processed, and result is synchronized in FE tables (cassandra)
6. Client comes with read for entity to you FE table, you retrieve those fast enough because of low latency/caching. Or you send them ["retry-after"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After) which tells them to wait just a bit and retry. They can gobble up their own CPU/IO to wait for it (here is where you gain your performance, return your strong consistency and converting their resources to your money =) ).

This way you can scale up/down FE load and BE load. FE has low latency, fast read/update operations without even single 500 error, all under 1-150ms, can be Geo-distributed, best user experience and availability here. BE has high latency (up to minutes/days), can drop-dead sometimes, lives in single region usually, can be updated frequently, but can process much faster in batches at lower costs and retry if something goes wrong.

That's it. This is how most successful companies do this, holy grail of distribution and you yourself probably already seen a variant of it (it can be far more complex and with other stack, but never changes from my experience).

You can try to optimize your code (like @Steve suggested), but **you will never be faster than eventually consistent** model. Right now your service is **strong consistent** - it's result is available straight after update, locking your client and resources at server, waiting for something to happen or fail, which is your main bottleneck. Not your code, IIS or lack of containerization (well it is inefficient, but is not important right now).

Comment: Both the .NET tier and the SQL Server tier can process a large number of concurrent requests.

Comment: No doubt. But it is vertical scaling, which has exponential costs, whereas my answer mostly on horizontal, which has linear costs. They do process large number of request if you stick around GC, pooling, transactions long enough and make various jeddy hacks. OP obviously has some window for improvement, but going further than that is overkill for simple problem.

Comment: Vertical scaling is linear up to the size of a commodity server, which is something like 40 cores. And the .net tier scales horizontally.

Comment: Well I said exactly that. Isn't it?

Comment: You said "vertical scaling, which has exponential costs", which is only true beyond a certain point.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend moving CRUD from database concurrency to a message queue. Particularly in this case where the problem candidate is just (inefficient) read activity